# Implementing a persistent redelivery in a Java Boot integration microservice using Apache Camel and/or ActiveMQ

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-camel, microservices, activemq-classic

I want to develop a small integration microservice, which implements communication between two existing systems.

System A has an Apache Kafka topics producing and consuming messages.

System B has a REST API and is capable calling a REST API callbacks.

Solution I'm trying to develop has to be able to communicate with each system, transform the messages and deliver it to another system (while doing extensive logging etc). The amount messages and the size of messages is *small*. Performance will not be an issue.

My chosen stack is Spring Boot + Apache Camel for routing + ELK for logging (+ templating engine etc, which is not really relevant).

My main concern is the requirement for a guaranteed delivery. From what I've read Camel stores the messages in memory, which means restarting/updating my microservice could lose some data which is inacceptable.

What are the relevant industry standards for implementing the guaranteed delivery?
I'm looking into ActiveMQ, but not sure if I need to bring the big guns since the solution is small and the amount of data is small. I'm not too opposed to the idea though.

I guess my questions are

1. What are the elegant ways of implementing persistent guaranteed delivery when integrating a 3rd party Kafka with a 3rd party REST systems.
2. Is bringing a whole message broker for the sake of a small microservice too much?

Comment: Typically guaranteed delivery between two systems is implemented using XA transactions (which uses a two phase commit protocol). However, Apache Kafka doesn't support XA transactions. What do you mean by "the big guns"? Is ActiveMQ a "big gun"? If so, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In short-- no, there is not an 'elegant' way to implement that. Kafka really can't do guaranteed delivery in the original sense of the meaning. Kafka solutions generally rely on all endpoints supporting the ability to replay the same data multiple times (or consumers having the ability to track what has been delivered already and drop repetitive messages). Same with REST-- REST endpoints (and HTTP in general, do not support guaranteed delivery.
2. This is a subjective question, but I'll try to answer objectively-- ActiveMQ has a smaller footprint than Kafka. If you are using Camel, you can readily co-locate small footprint ActiveMQ brokers with the Camel routes. This is a common architecture-- and one that has been around since Camel's inception. Alternatively, if the message volume is low a stand-alone ActiveMQ broker is as simple as running a single container or Java process.

"Kafka to Queued Messaging" is a common pattern to then provide guaranteed delivery to other systems. This centralizes the error handling and retry for network links to the queued messaging broker. Your Camel routes would then read from the queue(s). You can safely treat a queue-to-one-REST-endpoint as XA-like guaranteed delivery using JMS local-transactions.